# PHP mysqli does not insert into database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am very familiar with PHP, but this is my first time using the mysqli library. I am trying to insert a row into the database and it just does not insert. My code look like this (database login details changed for security):

```
... // $_REQUEST variables processed
$oConn = new mysqli("localhost","user","password","mydatabase") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($oConn));

$rProvider = $oConn->query("select * from providers where id = $iProviderID");
$aProvider = mysqli_fetch_array($rProvider);
// $aProvider has all the information from the provider that I wanted, so my database connection is working

$oConn->query("insert into bookings (provider_id, provider_rates_id, secret, preferred_date, alternate_date, adults, children, transfer_required, firstname, lastname, email, phone, comments) values
    ($iProviderID, $iRatesID, $sSecret, '$sDate', '$sAltDate', $iAdults, $iChildren, $iTransfer, '$sFirstNameSQL', '$sLastNameSQL', '$sEmailSQL', '$sPhoneSQL', '$sCommentsSQL'");

$iBookingID = $oConn->insert_id;
```

I am getting no error and $iBookingID is 0. The row just doesn't get inserted into the database. I have gone through the PHP manual and similar posts on StackExchange, but have not been able to resolve this issue.

Comment: @Amal Murali, thank you very much. Your suggestion helped me to fix two problems in my query which was causing it to fail. I would think that it would output these errors automatically, but obviously I was wrong. Again, thank you.

Comment: As per @Amul Murali's comment, it seems that mysqli does not automatically output errors and you must explicitly force it to do so by adding "or (die $mysqli->error);" after your query (where $mysqli is replaced with your object variable. In my case $oConn).

Comment: Take a look at the " ' " in your insert statement. Shouldn't the fieldnames be quoted, and the values only quoted accoding to type? insert into ('field1','field2',...) values (123, 123, 'secret','2013-01-01', ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

typo-u forgot to add single quotes and also a bracket.

```
$oConn->query("insert into bookings (provider_id, provider_rates_id, secret, preferred_date, alternate_date, adults, children, transfer_required, firstname, lastname, email, phone, comments) values
    ('$iProviderID', '$iRatesID', '$sSecret', '$sDate', '$sAltDate', '$iAdults', '$iChildren', '$iTransfer', '$sFirstNameSQL', '$sLastNameSQL', '$sEmailSQL', '$sPhoneSQL', '$sCommentsSQL')");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    ... // $_REQUEST variables processed
    $oConn = new mysqli("localhost","user","password","mydatabase") or die("Error " . $oConn->error);

    $oConn->query("insert into bookings (provider_id, provider_rates_id, secret, preferred_date, alternate_date, adults, children, transfer_required, firstname, lastname, email, phone, comments) values
        ('$iProviderID', '$iRatesID', '$sSecret', '$sDate', '$sAltDate', '$iAdults', '$iChildren', '$iTransfer', '$sFirstNameSQL', '$sLastNameSQL', '$sEmailSQL', '$sPhoneSQL', '$sCommentsSQL')");

    $iBookingID = $oConn->insert_id;
    echo $iBookingID;
```

Comment: if you only want to insert data so above query is perfect for you.

Answer (score 0):

there's a typo on your code, you're missing to close the ")" of the values part of your query.

The correct, query:

```
$oConn->query("insert into bookings (provider_id, provider_rates_id, secret, preferred_date, alternate_date, adults, children, transfer_required, firstname, lastname, email, phone, comments) values ($iProviderID, $iRatesID, $sSecret, '$sDate', '$sAltDate', $iAdults, $iChildren, $iTransfer, '$sFirstNameSQL', '$sLastNameSQL', '$sEmailSQL', '$sPhoneSQL', '$sCommentsSQL');");
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is not a php error, you can try using `echo $oConn->error` to get mysql query error!